# Timeout when trying to create elasticsearch index

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to create an elasticsearch index and am getting a timeout error. The commented out code works fine, so the server is running and is pingable. Here is my code:

```
import * as elasticsearch from "elasticsearch";

export const elasticClient = new elasticsearch.Client({  
    host: 'localhost:9200',
    log: 'trace',
    requestTimeout: 30000
});

// elasticClient.ping({
//   requestTimeout: 30000,
// }, function (error) {
//   if (error) {
//     console.error('elasticsearch cluster is down!');
//   } else {
//     console.log('All is well');
//   }
// });

// elasticClient.cluster.health({},function(err:any,resp:any) {  
//   console.log("-- Client Health --",resp);
// });

elasticClient.indices.create({  
  index: 'grr'
},function(err,resp,status) {
  if(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
  else {
    console.log("create",resp);
  }
});
```

Here is the error message:

```
Elasticsearch INFO: 2017-06-17T02:36:12Z


Adding connection to http://localhost:9200/

Elasticsearch DEBUG: 2017-06-17T02:36:12Z
  starting request {
    "method": "PUT",
    "path": "/grr",
    "query": {}
  }


{ Error: Request Timeout after 30000ms
    at C:\Users\myname\myproject\node_modules\elasticsearch\src\lib\transport.js:342:15
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (C:\Users\myname\myproject\node_modules\elasticsearch\src\lib\transport.js:371:7)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:365:14)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:237:5)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:207:5)
  status: 408,
  displayName: 'RequestTimeout',
  message: 'Request Timeout after 30000ms' }
Elasticsearch TRACE: 2017-06-17T02:36:42Z
  -> PUT http://localhost:9200/grr

  <- 0
```

I am really at a loss of what's going on. I'm using version 13.1.0 of the elasticsearch.js library

edit:
I've also tried using a curl statement (taken directly from the official site and modified to work in a Windows command prompt) to create the index and am having a similar issue, except it doesn't time-out; it just goes into an infinite loop.

Comment: Does manually issuing a request to create the index work?  What version of ES?

Comment: 5.4.1. How do I manually issue a request? I'm pretty new to all this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ended up being my Symantec Antivirus!! I uninstalled it and everything works as normal.

Comment: Symantec antivirus is probably the worst one out there, right next to McAffee